# Dedicating Bandwidth to a Certain Computer

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, samba

### Fundamental Question

What can I do to dedicate bandwidth to a Linux server running Ubuntu 12.04 so that other computers on the network can access the server with minimal lag?

### Background Information

- On the Linux server, I have an Apache web server, Samba File Sharing Server, PS3MediaServer, etc. When I am using Samba to mount a network drive on client computers, oftentimes it lags when playing movies.
- It has Ethernet connection straight to the router. (DD-WRT isn't an option because my router doesn't support it).

### Extra Information

- I am using an AirPlayIt server that I installed to stream to Apple products, and it *never* lags when viewing movies on the iPad.

**Note**: I would be happy to post additional information or output of Terminal commands if need be.

Comment: What do you mean here by "bandwidth"? Are you talking about computers on your LAN accessing the server, or remote computers?

Comment: Computers on my LAN accessing the server. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: It sounds like you need to get a better switch, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what bandrami said in comments: this is a hardware issue. If you're experiencing lag it means there isn't enough total bandwidth in your networking hardware to keep up. More local bandwidth means eliminate the bottlenecks. Make sure every piece of your equipment can do gigabit, including the NICs on your server and endpoints.

There's no magic software that can squeeze lots of data into a tiny hole quickly.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Right now, my setup is compromised of a combined modem, router, and switch. Would it be a better idea to have it as separate devices?

Comment: I've never seen a router/switch combo...but if it's from your ISP, you probably shouldn't mess with it. I would get a gigabit router and a gigabit switch, and create a new LAN underneath your existing equipment.